# what mathematical theorem is this

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Reading **Gödel, Escher, Bach** by Douglas R. Hofstadter, at p. 552, Achilles asks the Crab to play this piece:

∀a:∃b:∃c:<~∃d:∃e:<(SSd * SSe) = b ν (SSd * SSe) = c> ^ (a+a)=(b+c)>

And it seems that the Crab wasn't capable of playing this.

What is this composition stating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a theorem (yet); it's the Goldbach conjecture.  In English, it reads, "For all $a$, there exist $b$ and $c$ such that neither $b$ nor $c$ are expressible as the product of two numbers $d+2$ and $e+2$ (i.e., $b$ and $c$ are either $0$, $1$, or primes) and $b+c = 2a$."  (All numbers $a$ through $e$ are assumed to be non-negative integers in $\mathsf{TNT}$.)

Or, more concisely, "Every even number $\geq 4$ is the sum of two primes."  The wording allows us to ignore the cases where $2a = 0$ or $2$, since they are the sum of qualifying $b$ and $c$ (either $0+0$ or $1+1$).

That's why Achilles indirectly calls the situation a "Prime teas." :-)

(Incidentally, in the original hardback from Basic Books, this particular passage is at the bottom of p. $557$.)

Comment: Wait ... 557 is a prime that has 3 prime digits, namely 2 digits 5 and then a 7, so the digit sum is 17 ....

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Why is that relevant? (Where do digits come into this?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber The page number?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Brian's remark suggest that Hofstadter might have specifically aimed to have that *prime teas(e)* occur on a prime numbered page. This may be true - I could easily imagine Hofstadter doing that - but maybe it's not. Nevertheless I wanted to add to that observation just some random thoughts abou even more primes occuring "in" the page number, though these happen to be true mostly by the law of small numbers ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: It may have suggested that to you, but that was not my intent. :-P  I mentioned it only because $557 \not= 552$.  (You may have guessed that anyway, but I thought I'd mention it.)